# MAMP PRO PostFix

Tags: php, web, macos, postfix

acabo de comprar un mac y he comprado MAMP PRO para desarrollo web y me funciona de lujo. El problema es que soy bastante novato en mac / mamp y no se como configurar MAMP PRO Postfix. Según veo en la documentación tan solo tengo que poner como Domain : gmail.com y me debería de funcionar. Pero no es así.
Lo que necesito es configurarlo de forma que a través de código se envie desde from: xxxx.xxx a varios mails.

A alguien mas le ha pasado? Me podéis ayudar?

gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acabo de ver que no es compatible con Gmail tal y como dice su documentación.
https://documentation.mamp.info/en/MAMP-PRO-Mac/Servers-and-Services/Postfix/

gracias